# Классы в питоне и tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять что я упускаю. Пытаюсь разобраться с классами в питоне. Сделал простейшую программку. Ее задача рисовать шарик, удалять его и рисовать его в другом месте. Методом структурного программирования это легко получается, а вот при попытке сделать класс "шарик" и двигать его получается ерунда. В комментариях описал ход своих мыслей. Буду очень благодарен.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange as rnd, choice


class Ball:
#Шарик со случайными координатами и цветом в пределах канваса    
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = rnd(100, 700)
        self.y = rnd(100, 500)
        self.r = rnd(30, 50)
        colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue']
        canv.create_oval(self.x-self.r, self.y-self.r,
                                     self.x+self.r,self.y+self.r,
                                     fill = choice(colors), width=1)


def main():
    global canv
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x600')
    canv = Canvas(root,bg='white')
    canv.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    new_ball=Ball()         #Создаю экземпляр шарика. Объект новый шарик
    new_ball                #Рисую его на холсте
    print('x=',new_ball.x,  #Печатаю координвты, вижу что они доступны
          'y=',new_ball.y,
          'r=',new_ball.r)
    canv.delete(new_ball)   #Хочу удалить с холста но не удаляется
    new_ball.x=100          #Меняю атрибут экземпляра шара (координата х)
    print('x=',new_ball.x)  #Вижу что успешно поменялось значение
    new_ball                #Хочу нарисовать еще один с новой х но ничего
                            #не происходит            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: вызывайте функцию со скобками: `new_ball()`

Comment: `new_ball                #Рисую его на холсте` - эта строка на самом деле ничего не делает. У вас рисование происходит в момент создания объекта, когда вызывается `canv.create_oval`. По логике вашего кода чтобы нарисовать новый шарик нужно создать еще один экземпляр класса `Ball`.

Comment: @Victor, объект класса Ball из вопроса не callable, поэтому вызов его со скобками приведет к ошибке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комментарии по вашему коду

```
new_ball                #Рисую его на холсте
```

На самом деле нет: эта строка вообще ничего не делает, а шарик уже нарисован при создании объекта `Ball`, когда в методе `__init__` был вызван метод `canv.create_oval`.

```
canv.delete(new_ball)   #Хочу удалить с холста но не удаляется
```

Конечно не удаляется, потому что холст ничего не знает о вашем классе `Ball`. Метод `delete` холста должен получать на вход строку с идентификатором удаляемого объекта (например, то что вернул метод `create_oval`) или тегом удаляемых объектов (к нескольким объектам на холсте можно привязать текстовый тег, и работать с ними как с одним объектом).

```
new_ball                #Хочу нарисовать еще один с новой х но ничего
                        #не происходит
```

То же самое что и в первом случае - эта строка ничего не делает.

Вот рабочий пример:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange as rnd, choice
import time

class Ball:
    # Шарик со случайными координатами и цветом в пределах канваса    
    def __init__(self, canv):
        self.canv = canv
        self.x = rnd(100, 700)
        self.y = rnd(100, 500)
        self.r = rnd(30, 50)
        colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue']
        self.id = canv.create_oval(self.x-self.r, self.y-self.r,
                                   self.x+self.r, self.y+self.r,
                                   fill=choice(colors), width=1)

    def delete(self):
        self.canv.delete(self.id)

    def move(self):
        self.canv.coords(self.id, self.x-self.r, self.y-self.r,
                                  self.x+self.r, self.y+self.r)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x600')
    canv = Canvas(root,bg='white')
    canv.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    # Вместо использования глобальной переменной передаем холст при создании объекта
    new_ball = Ball(canv)
    print('x=',new_ball.x,
          'y=',new_ball.y,
          'r=',new_ball.r)

    root.update()  # Обновляем окно, чтобы изменения (только что созданный шарик) отобразились до паузы
    time.sleep(1)

    new_ball.x = 100
    print('x=', new_ball.x)
    new_ball.move()  # Переместить шарик по координатам, которые в нем хранятся
    root.update()  # Обновляем окно, чтобы изменения отобразились до паузы
    time.sleep(1)

    new_ball.delete()  # Удаляем шарик с помощью его метода
    # После удаления в данной реализации класса Ball заново отобразить его не получится

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Я использовал `time.sleep`, чтобы изменения были видны глазу (без `sleep` и `root.update` мы бы увидели только конечное состояние после удаления шарика).

Вообще, `time.sleep` в оконных приложениях лучше не использовать, т.к. пока длится пауза окно подвисает. Вместо этого лучше использовать планировать выполнение действий (функции) с помощью метода `root.after(delay, func)`, где `delay` - задержка, `func` - функция которую нужно выполнить после задержки.